# How to autocomplete columns when going down one row in Excel 2013?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2013, autocomplete

In my excel sheet I have values that could be automatically filled upon going down to an empty row.

My excel sheet has this structure:

[image]

If I go from Row 3 down to Row 4 i would have to insert the Date and Start time again. It would make my life a lot easier if those values were auto completed by the current Date and the End time of the row above.

[image]

Is there any way to do this in Excel 2013 without using VB Scripts (they are not compatible with MAC Computers)?

Answer (score 0):

If you manually type the date twice as the same, you can drag it down and it won't increase.

For the other part, just set `B3 = C2` and as it drags down it will always reference the end time above.

You can drag both columns at the same time.

Comment: I do not want to drag something down nor copy some formatting through all the rows below. Im searching for an autocomplete option that fires when I go down 1 row.

Comment: Then you will need VBA.